# 1970s SF story of aliens on earth farming brains for use in war machines - anyone read it and remember what it was called?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The aliens were often disguised as pretty women and the protagonist goes underground to battle them but is overpowered and ends up waking up as an alien tank on another world. He manages to telepathically wake up other brains in neighbouring tanks and they use their new fighting abilities to overpower the aliens and send word back to Earth warning them of the farming operations.

Comment: See apparent confirmation comment (presumably by OP from non-linked account user14901) on answer below.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds very similar in plot to "A Plague Of Demons". URL: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1829054.Plague_of_Demons

The earliest I could find is "A Plague Of Demons" being published in 1985 and the aliens didn't use women as the recruitment method.

Edit: sjl found it was originally published in 1964 in serialized format, and first published as one complete work in May 1965 under the self titled "A Plague Of Demons".

Comment: _A Plague of Demons_ was first published in 1964 and was reprinted many times before 1985: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1385.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks. I read it in the early 1970s as a teenager and the story has stayed with me. Now I can read it again...

Comment: @sjl, thanks! I've updated the answer with the information you found.